# 'MSize' is not a member of cv::Mat

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, mat

I'm trying to run this repo for curiosity: https://github.com/jzeimen/PuzzleSolver/tree/master/PuzzleSolver

Eclipse throws the title error "'MSize' is not a member of cv::Mat' whenever I try to run the following line of code from PuzzleDisjointSet.cpp:

```
cv::Mat::MSize size_of_a = sets[rep_a].locations.size;
```

Where locations is defined like so:

```
struct forest{
    cv::Mat_<int> locations;
    cv::Mat_<int> rotations;
    int representative;
    int id;
};
```

and sets is a vector version of the forest structure. I'm mainly confused as to why this is occurring, when [documentation clearly refutes this](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/structcv_1_1Mat_1_1MSize.html).

I believe the header files I am including are the correct ones (PuzzleDisjointSet.h includes the above forest structure definition as well as the sets definition.

```
#include "PuzzleDisjointSet.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
```

Comment: Can you update with the exact error message(s)? Sometimes the struct may not be defined because something else happened.

Comment: @Rome_Leader  I have just built that repo with Eclipse CDT 3.8.1 without encountering that error. You "believe the header files you are including are correct". So are you not simply building the source as you find it in the repo and linking it with opencv?

Comment: I don't know much about opencv but [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/core.html) documentation has nothing about Mat containing a sub structure named MSize. You sure you're compiling with the right OpenCV? Did you check the header files?

Comment: @CássioRenan The exact error message is: 'MSize is not a member of 'cv::Mat'. Thanks to the other answer below, I now know there was some refactoring of the cv::Mat class in the latest OpenCV (3.0) release. Looking into it ATM.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Which version of OpenCV did you use? I was using 3.0, and am trying a rollback to 2.4.9 as we speak.

Comment: @Rome_Leader I'm away from the machine right now but I believe 2.4.11. Definitely not 3.0. The doc link in your post refers ro 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the struct was removed in this commit 
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/d8c8339bec83b77978d2a0e1a62b764fb9d9c599#diff-bc1d784738cd852f5b1e95ce10a56d06

maybe you can checkout a version before that and use it, or i suspect it may have been moved to a different class, you can try looking for that

Comment: Ahh, right you are! I'll roll back to 2.4.9 just as a test and report back if the error still occurs. 2.4.4 appears totally deprecated at this point, but I suspect they might still be similar enough. Thanks!

Comment: The problem still persists even at 2.4.9. Any idea how I could get a file for OpenCV 2.4.4, since this seems to be the last tested OpenCV release?

Comment: you can clone the repo and try to build it on a branch **before** 2.4, but i suggest you go through the code and make it compile on the newer versions. or maybe ask some of the devs there for help via mailing lists and such.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV version: 4.3.0

```
cv::MatSize size_of_a = sets[rep_a].locations.size;
```